# Want to remove "Compare Prod" from SideBar?

Tags: compare

I have successfully removed the "Compare Prd" feature from my Site, but the SideBar "Compare Prd" is still showing.

How can i remove it from the **HomePage, Catalog Page & Single Prod Page** ?

http://postimg.org/image/exu16gn7v/

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to one of your layout files:

```
<default>
    <reference name="right"><!-- in case the compare block is on the right sidebar -->
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left"><!-- in case the compare block is on the leftsidebar -->
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

**[EDIT]**
If the method above does not work (it seams it doesn't), edit `catalog.xml` layout file and remove any trace of the blocks named `catalog.compare.sidebar`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind telling me the precise Folder/file ?

Comment: add it in `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml`. Just make sure you add it inside the `<layout>` tag

Comment: OK - my local.xml file does'nt seem to be work as i tried to hide "Disc Coupon" block but did'nt succeed.  But will try your code & let you know.

Comment: << Unfortunately - not working even clearing all caches. >>  << http://postimg.org/image/tdaxr5fwh/ >>                           << Folder: /app/design/frontend/default/MAG090172/layout/local.xml >>

Comment: << Code: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layout> 
<default>
    <reference name="right"><!-- in case the compare block is on the right sidebar -->
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left"><!-- in case the compare block is on the leftsidebar -->
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
 >>

Comment: Hi Marius - any thoughts why the local.xml is not working ?  Is there alterative ?

Comment: I have no idea why it's not working with `local.xml`. It should. I will update the answer with an other way to do it.

Comment: Hi Marius - edited the catalog.xml file but still NOT working ! <<Folder: /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml>>  <<cCode Removed:  Line 56
<block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
Line 166
<action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action> >> QTN: Is it the correct Folder ??

Comment: @Mave Maybe you are editing the wrong file. Check if there is a `catalog.xml` in your theme folder.

Comment: Hi Marius - NOW it's working !!! THANKS, THANKS, THANKS !!!

Comment: where do i do that from ?

Comment: Below the vote arrows on this answer there is a "checkmark". If you hover it, it will say something like "Accept this answer". Click it.